# mapping multiple points on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a set of lat long points in php array $col_1_values_array for latitude and $col_2_values_array for longitude. I want to map all these points on a Google map and draw a route on them. I have written this code in Javascript, but it is not showing markers on points. Kindly help me find the mistake.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { initialize(); });
   function initialize() {
        var map_options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $col_1_values_array[0] ?>,<?php echo $col_2_values_array[0] ?>),

            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var google_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), map_options);

        var info_window = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'loading'
        });


        var x = [];
        var y = [];

        var routePoints = [];
        for(<?php $r=0;$r<25;$r++ ?>)
        {
        x.push(<?php echo $col_1_values_array[$r]?>);
        y.push(<?php echo $col_2_values_array[$r] ?>);
}


        var i = 0;
        for (var p=0;p<25;p++) {
        routePoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(x[p],y[p]));
            var m = new google.maps.Marker({
                map:       google_map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title:     t[p],
                position:  new google.maps.LatLng(x[p],y[p]),
                html:      h[i]
            });
var route= new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: routePoints,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2 
  });



            google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function() {
                info_window.setContent(this.html);
                info_window.open(google_map, this);

            });
            i++;
        }

    route.setMap(google_map);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: WHAT happened on first edit!?!

Answer (score 0):

You may have timing issue, try doing the marker work in the initalize map event.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);